# Python: TypeError: 'exp' object is not callable

Tags: python, sympy, callable

while writing programm finding solutions of the equation I get following TypeError: 'exp' object is not callable. I don't understand what my mistake is...

code below:

```
from scipy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
from sympy import *
import sys
import numpy
import cmath
import math
from scipy import optimize

from sympy.solvers import solve

file=open('solve1.txt','w')
print 'Start'

y=Symbol('y')

equat1=exp(-1.0j*(36.96*y**0.5+1.367*(-1.25*y+2.33)**0.5+30.996*(1.25*y-0.675)**0.5))

Solution1 = optimize.brenth(equat1, 0.11, 0.14)

print 'Solution first:'
print Solution1
file.write(str(Solution1))

file.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of [brenth](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brenth.html) must be callable (a Python function), representing the objective function. Your `equat1` is a SymPy expression (of class `exp`, since its outermost layer is `exp` function), and this is not callable.

One can use [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to make a callable out of a SymPy expression:

```
optimize.brenth(lambdify(y, equat1), 0.11, 0.14)
```

This executes, but with (appropriate) warnings about complex values. `brenth` expects a real valued function. Generally, one cannot expect both real and imaginary part to vanish at the same point, anyway. Lastly, the function `exp` never turns to zero, so what do you really expect to obtain? Consider if you meant to equate to zero the real part, or imaginary part, or  something else.

You don't really need SymPy at all; defining a callable directly allows

```
equat1 = lambda y: (a formula returning the thing to be equated to 0)
```

This way you'd have more control over the handling of complex values; potentially using `cmath`, or declaring `complex` dtype in NumPy. As is, there are issues with `sqrt` of a negative number because NumPy will not automatically  cast real to complex data type. Here is a working snippet based on your equation: I used cmath.sqrt so that roots of negative numbers are handled correctly.

```
import cmath
from scipy import optimize
equat1 = lambda y: cmath.exp(-1.0j*(36.96*y**0.5+1.367*cmath.sqrt(-1.25*y+2.33)+30.996*cmath.sqrt(1.25*y-0.675))).real
print(optimize.fsolve(equat1, 0.11))    #  array([ 0.1073826])
```

---

Aside: using `from module import *` for multiple modules is not a good idea, as imports will overwrite each other, resulting in a mess.

Comment: Thanks for your help! 
What I need to do: I have a complicated equation of type A*B*C and I need to find all zeros of real part of A, B and C in [a;b]. Maybe is better way to do this? Can I operate in any way only on real part of equations? Maybe there is a function in python which can find all roots in [a;b]?

Comment: There is no function to find all roots. Bisection methods will find one root. However, with your initial interval [0.11, 0.14] brenth cannot start because it's not a valid bracketing interval: the objective function does not have different signs at the ends. In my snippet I used fsolve instead.

Comment: I'd tried with solution you suggested, and get:

"TypeError: can't convert complex to float"

Arghhh...

Comment: I found out whats goin' on. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

exp is the function of numpy , you have to either import it or call it using numpy

```
from numpy import exp
```

Comment: That's not the function the OP wants to use, their goal is to use exp from SymPy.